# burpsuite onion http request intercept

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, proxy, torsocks, onionaddress

I have an Onion Website, and i want to try and exploit it to find the Real IP-Address behind this Service.

The problem:

'Cannot intercept Traffic from .onion' i also used this Settings in BurpSuite:

[image: socks img]

I even try to set the Settings in Tor Browser as 'http proxy' ip : 127.0.0.1 , and port 8080
but i cannot see any Request Intercepted.

Can someone help me with this, i really need to test and attack my own Onion Page.

Answer (score 0):

Tor browser will not obey you here - use Firefox. Tor Browser is a Firefox ESR twisted for tor's team vision of privacy. Your proxy config is fine - just launch tor binary standalone, use burpsuite as you've configured it and point Firefox to your burpsuite proxy. This will work